# How to measure process awake time (system not asleep)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a Python 3 script to measure the running time of a process, since it keeps dying and I'm interested in how long it will keep actively running. But it's running on my laptop, and I realized the statistics will be skewed by periods when I've put it to sleep.

It's on Linux, so I'm sure there's a log file I could parse (it used to be `pm-suspend.log` before systemd), but I'm wondering if there's a more general/direct way.

Can a process ask to be notified of suspend events?

I should note that I'm interested in the wallclock time the process was running, not the actual CPU execution time. So `time.process_time()` won't work.

Answer (score -1):

It includes the suspended periods but as far as i think it is the only option to find the process running time.Moreover using this you can even find the running time of even individual lines of code.

```
from time import time
t0=time()
#your code here
print(time()-t0)
```

Comment: Thanks, but how does this avoid including asleep time? `time.time()` gives wallclock time, so the difference you show includes suspended periods.

Comment: Better add some explanation to your answer rather than just post the code.

Comment: yes it includes the suspended periods but as far as i think it is the only option to find the process running time.Moreover using this you can even find the running time of even individual lines of code.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link under your contribution to supplement it with additional information. Comments on Stack Overflow are "ephemeral" - they tend to disappear.

Comment: @yaswanthvanama Sorry, the only point of the question is how to exclude asleep time. Maybe I should've explicitly said, but I'm looking for an alternative to the standard `time.time()` method.